How to get pickerStyle(.navigationLink) to scroll automatically to the selected value
I wish to use a picker with pickerStyle(.navigationLink) to select a value.
The list of values is long and so I would expect the picker list on the new screen to scroll automatically to ensure the currently selected value is visible. However on the new screen the first page is displayed regardless and you need to scroll manually to reach the selected value if it lies outside it.
Scrolling automatically occurs for pickerStyle(.menu) and pickerStyle(.wheel).
Is there a way of making pickerStyle(.navigationLink) reflect the same behaviour?
Demonstation code below:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedValue: Int = 56
    let values = 0..<101
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            Form {
                Picker("Pick a value", selection:$selectedValue) {
                    ForEach(values, id:\.self) {
                        Text($0, format: .number)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.navigationLink)
            }
        }
    }
}



@sweeper Yes please!

@sweeper Many thanks - a lot to pick out and digest in these (for my current skill level in SwiftUI). I will work through them and mark up as answer once fully assimilated and understood.

You can put the selected element as the first Element of your List, if that is suitable to your use-case.

Really the only important part is .onAppear { proxy.scrollTo(selection) }, where the scrolling actually happens. Everything else is just to recreate the behaviour of the built-in picker. Feel free to ask in the comments of my answer if you have questions about the code.

You can create your own picker view that does this. Here is an example:
struct NavigationLinkPicker<Label: View, Content: View, Options: RandomAccessCollection>: View where Options.Element: Hashable {
    typealias Selection = Options.Element
    let label: Label
    let options: Options
    @Binding var selection: Selection
    let content: (Selection) -> Content
    
    init(options: Options, selection: Binding<Selection>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Selection) -> Content, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label) {
        self.options = options
        self._selection = selection
        self.content = content
        self.label = label()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        LabeledContent {
            NavigationLink {
                NavigationDestination(
                    selection: $selection,
                    options: options,
                    content: content
                )
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    if let selectedOption = options.first(where: { $0 == selection }) {
                        content(selectedOption)
                    }
                }
            }
        } label: {
            label
        }
    }
    
    struct NavigationDestination: View {
        @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
        
        @Binding var selection: Selection
        @State var listSelection: Selection?
        let options: Options
        let content: (Selection) -> Content
        
        var body: some View {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                List(options, id: \.self, selection: $listSelection) { option in
                    HStack {
                        content(option)
                        Spacer()
                        if option == selection {
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                .bold()
                                .foregroundStyle(Color.accentColor)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: listSelection) { _, newValue in
                    guard let newValue else { return }
                    Task {
                        // dismiss must be called with a little delay,
                        // or else the navigation destination is pushed again after dismissing
                        // for some reason
                        dismiss()
                    }
                    selection = newValue
                }
                .onAppear {
                    proxy.scrollTo(selection)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Example usage:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedValue: Int = 56
    let values = 0..<101
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            Form {
                NavigationLinkPicker(options: values, selection:$selectedValue) {
                    Text($0, format: .number)
                } label: {
                    Text("Pick a value")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The above implementation requires you to pass in a RandomAccessCollection to populate the picker with views. If you would like a usage more similar to the built-in picker, you can use this design instead, which depends on View Extractor.
import ViewExtractor

struct NavigationLinkPicker<Label: View, Content: View, Selection: Hashable>: View {
    let label: Label
    @Binding var selection: Selection
    let content: Content
    
    init(selection: Binding<Selection>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label) {
        self._selection = selection
        self.content = content()
        self.label = label()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Extract(content) { options in
            LabeledContent {
                NavigationLink {
                    NavigationDestination(selection: $selection, options: options)
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        options.first(where: { $0.id(as: Selection.self) == selection })
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                label
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct NavigationDestination: View {
        @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
        
        @Binding var selection: Selection
        @State var listSelection: Selection?
        let options: Views
        
        var body: some View {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                List(options, selection: $listSelection) { option in
                    if let id = option.id(as: Selection.self) {
                        HStack {
                            option
                            Spacer()
                            if id == selection {
                                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                    .bold()
                                    .foregroundStyle(Color.accentColor)
                            }
                        }
                        .tag(id)
                        .id(id)
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: listSelection) { _, newValue in
                    guard let newValue else { return }
                    Task {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                    selection = newValue
                }
                .onAppear {
                    proxy.scrollTo(selection)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Note that in this design I am checking the ids of the views, not tag, so keep that in mind when using it. Reading tag is something internal to SwiftUI so we can't do that in our code.
Example usage:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedValue: Int = 56
    let values = 0..<101
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            Form {
                NavigationLinkPicker(selection:$selectedValue) {
                    ForEach(values, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0, format: .number)
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Pick a value")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Noted your comment about unexpectedly needing to place the dismiss() in a Task. Anyone have any ideas as to why?

Couple of other oddities. Formatting fails to compile for me in both implementations ie: Text("\(i)", format: .number) in RandomAccessCollection option and  Text("\(i)", format: .number).id(i) in ViewExtractor option with error Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs).

and also I get a compiler warning Non-constant range: not an integer range is issued for the ViewExtractor option if ForEach(0..<101) is replaced by ForEach(values) where values is defined as let values = 0..<101 as in my original demonstration test code.

@ChrisLindsey Well basic SwiftUI rules still apply... For a non-constant range, you still need id: \.self just like in the code in your question. Text("\(i)", format: .number) doesn't make sense. Did you mean Text(i, format: .number)?

Ah - of course! Yes - Text(i, format: .number) is what is required!

@ChrisLindsey I wasn't trying to apply the custom picker to the code in your question. The examples are just something I made up on the spot. I have edited the answer to recreate the picker in the question.

@ChrisLindsey I suspect the dismiss thing is just a bug. In iOS 16.4, the whole NavigationDestination view gets pushed again. In iOS 17.4, only an empty view gets pushed, so I think Apple is "gradually" fixing it. :) Perhaps try it without Task { ... } on iOS 18 if you have the beta (I don't).
